# how to setup moai 1.5 stable?

Tags: lua, moai

The links in moai are broken, so I went to github and downloaded the files as a zipped folder.

```
https://github.com/moai/moai-dev
```

Now it says I need to set the environment variables to

```
set MOAI_BIN=<install_path>¥moai-dev     ¥release¥win32¥host-sdl¥bin
set MOAI_CONFIG=<install_path>¥moai-dev¥samples¥config
```

I set up everything as above, however when i try to run a sample it says moai-bin link isn't correct. I checked the moai sdk folder, it doesn't even contain moai.exe. What should I do ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not on Windows. But the path separators in the README are wrong, so just checking the obvious, did you try setting the environment vars like so:

```
set MOAI_BIN=<install_path>\moai-dev\release\win32\host-sdl\bin
set MOAI_CONFIG=<install_path>\moai-dev\samples\config
```

And then running:

```
cd moai-dev
.\bin\build-win.bat
```

And make sure you have all the Windows dependencies installed, like Visual Studio? Check this list: https://github.com/moai/moai-dev#setup.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have downloaded source release and maybe did not build moai binary. You can just download [moai binary release](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/releases) which is available for linux, osx and windows. After unpacking point MOAI_BIN to proper moai binary.